# NextJS rewrites in production

Tags: javascript, proxy, url-rewriting, next.js

I discovered rewrites to proxy to my back end server in development:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

```
rewrites: async () => [
...nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
{ source: '/api/:path*', destination: 'http://localhost:8080/:path*' },
],
```

How does this work in production if the url will not be localhost?

For the destination do i need to add the full domain or do i need a separate rewrite rules for dev/production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the domain part from the destination and use `absolute` path.

```js
rewrites: async () => [
  ...nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  { source: '/api/:path*', destination: '/:path*' },
  // ------------------------------------^
];
```